# cannot access a div by id in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I'm new to React and js and in this code
Im trying to add access a div by it's id (gauge6) in useEffect. But it is showing as null
If useEffect is called after the component is rendered, i don't understand why it is null.

```
  useEffect (() =>
    {
      const dataArray = [];
        const ProduitsRef = fireDb.database().ref('produits')
          ProduitsRef.on('value', 
            (snapshot) => {
              if (snapshot.val() != null)
              {setProduits({
                ... snapshot.val()
              })
              console.log(produits);
              }
            }
          )
          var gauge6 = Gauge(
            document.getElementById("gauge6"), 
            {
              max: 100,
              dialStartAngle: 90.01,
              dialEndAngle: 89.99,
              dialRadius: 150,
              showValue: false,
              value: 50,
            }
          );
       }, []);

...

        <div id='mydiv' className='row'>

        { 
        produits 
        ? Object.keys(produits).map((id) =>  
        (
        
          <div key={id} className='col-4 border rounded m-3' align='center'>
          <h3> {produits[id].nom} </h3>
          <h3>Achete le: {produits[id].date_achat} </h3>

          <h3>A consommer: {produits[id].date_expiration} </h3>
          
                
                
          <FontAwesomeIcon className='m-1' icon={faTrash} onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}/>
          <FontAwesomeIcon className='m-1' icon={faEdit} onClick={() => handleupdate(id)}/>
             
          <div class="example">
            <div class="display">
              <div id="gauge6" class="gauge-container six"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          </div>
        
        ))
        : ''
      }
      </div>
```

I tried to create the elements inside useEffect with createElement, it is no more null in console, but it doesn't work and i don't find it in the elements of the page.

Please Help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not guaranteed to help, but there are some things you can try to debug the code.

1. `setState` in React is asynchronous under the hood. I'm guessing that you're seeing an empty object in `console.log(produits)`.
2. You conditionally render the gauges with a ternary operator (`produits? . . . : ''`). There's nothing wrong in that, but try typing something in the empty quotes and see if it's the second condition being rendered all the time.
3. Try moving out `.map` outside of the JSX. You'll get an opportunity to check what's being rendered by logging it before the return statement.

```js
const renderStack = Object.keys(produits).map((id) => {});
console.log(renderStack);
return <div id='mydiv' className='row'>{renderStack}</div>
```

4. Let's try not to `createElement` inside `useEffect`. While it's do-able, it might lead to hard-to-debug problems down the road. But if you really wanna do it, you need to call (parentElement).`appendChild`. Otherwise `const a = document.createElement(); console.log(a)` will not give you null, but the element is never mounted onto the DOM tree so it's not gonna be visible or accessible anywhere else.

---

**Edit:** I saw your reply, but that doesn't give me much insight to the problem. Nonetheless, I've made a demo [with CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gauge-demo-gzonm?file=/src/App.js) for you. Check it out and see if it helps.

Comment: 1 - yes, im seeing undefined for produits, 2 - when i type something, i dont see it, i always see the 'produits' displayed in divs 3- produits is undefined before return

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although that doesn't seem to give me much further clues. But I've edited my answer and added a demo. I hope it can be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` instead of `id`.

```js
const gauge6 = useRef(null);
```

```js
var gauge6 = Gauge(
  gauge6.current, 
  {
    max: 100,
    dialStartAngle: 90.01,
    dialEndAngle: 89.99,
    dialRadius: 150,
    showValue: false,
    value: 50,
  }
);
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <div ref={gauge6} class="gauge-container six"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MarwenHizaoui did you try to log gauge6 if it is `null` or not?

Comment: Okay, so the problem is `gauge6` will be `null` while `produits` is an empty array. `useEffect(() => {}, []) ` is called once after rendering, so at that point `produits` array is still an empty array because fetching from Firebase db is still in progress. Can you tell me when you want to get `gauge6`?

Comment: I want to display a gauge for every item in 'produits, by displaying a div for every item and inside that div a gauge